# Understanding how Haskell precedence rules work with multiple partial application

Tags: haskell

Please explain how Haskell determines precedence with sections, functions that take multiple arguments and multiple partially applied functions. Sometimes I find it hard to figure out which partial function will have which argument applied when whole expression takes multiple arguments.

Here are some example functions, however I'm sure different examples could be more illustrative. First one is taken from 'Applicative programming with effects' article.

```
sequence :: [IO a] → IO [a]
sequence [] = return []
sequence (c : cs) = return (:) `ap` c `ap` sequence cs

(.) (.)
(.) (.) (.)
```

Is there a tool to convert such expressions to lambda expression form?

Comment: If you're in the #haskell irc channel, you can use @unpl, which transforms the point-free versions into point-ful (lambda) versions. Example on (.) (.) (.):  (\ c e f i -> c (e f i))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of identifiers in a function application like `a b c d` is parsed as `(((a b) c) d)`.  The parenthesized infix operator `(.)` is treated like an identifier.

So `(.) (.) (.)` parses as `((.) (.)) (.)`.

In general, a variable operator like this

```
`functionname`
```

by default has left associativity, and lower precedence than function application, but this can be modified with an `infixl` or `infixr` declaration.  The `ap` function has not been modified from the default, so the rhs of `sequence` pases as:

```
((return (:)) `ap` c) `ap` (sequence cs)
```

or equivalently

```
ap (ap (return (:)) c) (sequence cs)
```

Comment: The "lower precedence than function application, but this can be modified" sentence is a bit awkward, one could read it as though an `infix` declaration could make a higher precedence than function application.

Comment: Why `(return (:)) \`ap\`` is not application of `ap` to `return (:)` but reads as a section? Are sections always "translated" like here to `ap (return (:))`?

Comment: @Rumca I don't know what you mean here by "section".  (x \`f\` y) parses as `f x y`, and x \`f\` y \`f\` z parses as (x \`f\` y) \`f\` z, or `f (f x y) z`.  As for why, I can only refer you to [The Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell98-report.pdf), section 3.2.

Answer (score 8):

An operator in parentheses with *no* arguments is treated just like a normal identifier. So `(+)` and `add` behave exactly the same way. This means it's used in *prefix* form, and precedence issues simply do not arise.

With that in mind, we could imagine writing the following:

```
compose = (.)
compose compose compose
```

The latter version is the same as the confusing version using `(.)`. It helps to remember that function application is right associative, so the expression is the same as:

```
(compose compose) compose
```

An operator section with an argument, like `(+ 1)` or `(1 +)` also behaves just like a normal identifier as far as precedence is concerned. So if you define `next = (+ 1)`, both will behave the same.

As far as point-free code goes, the [pointful](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointful) package has a command-line tool that takes a point-free function and tries to turn it into a bunch of lambdas. You can also get this functionality from lambdabot on the #haskell IRC channel with @unpl.

You can just install pointful with cabal and call it:

```
cabal install pointful
pointful
```

Comment: Why does it not parse as `(compose compose compose)` since compose takes two arguments?

Comment: @Rumca In Haskell, every function takes exactly one argument. Some, like `compose`, then return a function that takes another argument.