# What's the difference between the `sin sin 0.5` and the `sin (sin 0.5)` in haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

```
*> sin sin 0.5  
<interactive>:10:1:
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Floating (a -> a)
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
  it :: forall a. (Floating a, Floating (a -> a)) => a
```

but `sin (sin 0.5)` works. 
I think they are identical, and I can't understand the error message.
I want to know why?

Comment: They are not identical. Function application is left-associative, and so `sin sin 0.5` is actually `(sin sin) 0.5`, which is not what you meant and leads to a type error.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [Understanding how Haskell precedence rules work with multiple partial application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243075/understanding-how-haskell-precedence-rules-work-with-multiple-partial-applicatio)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: `sin sin 0.5` parses as `(sin sin) 0.5`

Long answer: The expression `sin sin 0.5` parses as `(sin sin) 0.5`. Now, the sine function works on any `Floating` type. So Haskell, trying to deduce the type of your expression, determines that `sin :: Floating a => a -> a` must be floating, so `Floating a => a -> a` is a floating point type. But Haskell doesn't allow complex types like `a -> a` to appear in context expressions, so you get that error. If Haskell allowed such expressions (or if you enabled FlexibleContexts, as the error suggests), you would get an uglier error when the types failed to unify later.